# Exception caught by widgets library ═ The method '+' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: +(" ")

Tags: flutter

Hi guys im new to flutter
im stuck on this error when i try to render a list of comments from my widget.

### Error i get

#### Exception caught by widgets library

The method '+' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: +(" ") 
The relevant error-causing widget was
CommentItem 
lib\…\Comments\main.dart:52

**My widget code**

```
class CommentItem extends StatefulWidget {
  CommentItem({Key key, this.comment}) : super(key: key);
  final CommentModel comment;

  @override
  _CommentItemState createState() => _CommentItemState();
}

class _CommentItemState extends State<CommentItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          widget.comment.user.picture != null
              ? avatar(url: widget.comment.user.picture)
              : const SizedBox.shrink(),
          commentDetails()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget commentDetails() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            userName(
                widget.comment.user.name + ' ' + widget.comment.user.surname), // error line
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            commentTimeStap(widget.comment.createdAt)
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        widget.comment.type == 'text'
            ? textCommentContent(widget.comment.body)
            : imageCommentContent(widget.comment.body),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        commentEdit(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget userName(String name) {
    return Text(
      name,
      style: userNameStyle(),
    );
  }

  Widget commentTimeStap(String time) {
    return Text(Helpers.timeAgoSinceDate(time));
  }

  Widget textCommentContent(String body) {
    return Text(
      body,
      style: commentContentStyle(),
    );
  }

  Widget imageCommentContent(String body) {
    return Image.network(
      Api.assetsurl + '/$body',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,
      height: 200,
    );
  }

  Widget commentEdit() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        widget.comment.type == 'text'
            ? commentButton('Edit', onClick: null)
            : Container(),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Text('.'),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        commentButton('Delete', onClick: () async {
          await deleteModal();
        }),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget commentButton(String text, {@required Function onClick}) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: onClick,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: commentButtonStyle(),
        ));
  }

  Future<void> deleteModal() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Are You Sure ?'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Once You Delete , It\'s Gone For Good.'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000)).then((value) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Delete Comment')),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000)).then((value) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Cancel'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

**My comment model**

```
import 'package:gn_plumbing/Core/models/user_model.dart';

class CommentModel {
  int id;
  String userId;
  String body;
  String type;
  String projectId;
  String createdAt;
  UserModel user;

  CommentModel(
      {this.id,
      this.userId,
      this.body,
      this.projectId,
      this.type,
      this.createdAt,
      this.user});

  factory CommentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    //* initialize comment creator
    var _user = new UserModel();
    if (json != null && json.containsKey("staff")) {
      _user = UserModel.fromJson(json['staff']);
    }

    return CommentModel(
        id: int.parse(json["id"].toString()) ?? 0,
        userId: json["user_id"] ?? "",
        body: json["body"] ?? "",
        type: json["type"] ?? "",
        createdAt: json["created_at"] ?? "",
        projectId: json["project_id"] ?? "",
        user: _user);
  }
}
```

**Json sample**

```
"comments": [
{
"id": 2,
"user": {
"id": 3,
"name": "Lucky",
"surname": "Motseki",
"id_number": 123456789654,
"picture": "1629103951.jpg",
"medical": "5362",
"rate": "4",
"contract": "1998-11-25",
"email": "lucky.m@dotcom.africa"
},
"body": "test",
"type": "text",
"created_at": "2021-02-05T12:00:25.000000Z"
},
]
```

**User Model**

```
class UserModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String surname;
  final String picture;
  final String email;
  final String medical;
  final String contract;

  UserModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.surname,
    this.picture,
    this.email,
    this.medical,
    this.contract,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json["name"],
      surname: json["surname"],
      picture: json["picture"],
      email: json["email"],
      medical: json["medical"],
      contract: json["contract"],
    );
  }
} // user class

class ApiTokenModel {
  String apiToken;

  ApiTokenModel({this.apiToken});

  factory ApiTokenModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ApiTokenModel(apiToken: json["authToken"] ?? "");
  }
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: can you add the user model code too

Comment: i will update now

Comment: have you checked the values of the first name and surname by debugger?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging follow the link

Comment: Thanks a lot Asim, but I resolved my issues using @MiguelRuivo answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have null types calling sum operation when they shouldn't. This approach would be easily solved by [migrating your project to null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide).

As of now, you can check for null in the line:

```
if(widget.comment.user != null && widget.comment.user.name != null)
userName(widget.comment.user.name + ' ' + widget.comment.user.surname),
```

Comment: Maybe the `user` is `null` as well. I don't have your user model. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, for some reason i had to do flutter clean and get packages again. when i ran the build again your answer work. I cant upvote your answer I dont have enough stars

Comment: Glad it worked. No problem, you can mark it as accepted only.